# Wordpress Change Css of theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Can I ask how to change the css of my theme to make the page looks like this http://katiefreiling.com/ this site has its navigation which is purple not extended until the left and right corner. My navigition seems to be extended from left and right corner and my content and footer too. Is it possible to have a style or format similar to the link above? Thanks in advance this is my website http://michelebrunello.com/.

Comment: yes its is possible would you mind copying the whole css of that example site and change the selector names accordingly this thing gonna help you for sure...

Comment: Hello Sir Pankaj, Im not good in css this my css code http://michelebrunello.com/wp-content/themes/freshnews/style.css any help would be highly appreciated Sir thaks in advance

Comment: I could have helped you but the thing which you want is kind of building the whole stuff again...

Comment: Is it rebuilding sir? or is just fixing some css selectors? thanks

Comment: It's better first learn css & html. Then ask any question if you stuck somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to learn the concepts first and then ask questions. I don't know what picture is in your mid exactly but as per your demo website given i have added few css rules in your css please see the below css rules and try to add in your css.

1. line 35 white.css

   ```
   #topmenu {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #212983;
   border-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 940px; }
   ```
2. line 11 white.css

   ```
   #footer-widgets {
   background-color: #FAFAFA;
   border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 960px; }
   ```
3. line 901 style.css

   ```
   #footer {
   background: url("images/bgr-box-trans.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #E4E2DB;
   border-top: 1px solid #EEECE6;
   font-size: 11px;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 22px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding: 20px 0; }
   ```

Try to implement the css first.

Comment: Hello Sir Happy, Wow you really made my day I've been doing this for time and have no luck, I can start from this understandin your code. Thank you very much. I've made it happened The only thing missing was the footer it is still in fullwidth Sir. Thank you very much! It is really deeply appreciated Sir

Comment: Hello Sir I've fixed it locally but I tried to upload the theme to the website it is still the same. I'm still trying to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: add width:960px to #footer on line 908 and remove padding in style.css

Comment: Hello Sir Thank You very much it worked on my localhost nicely but when I tried uploading the theme on my site the css I made was disregarded. Than you Sir

Comment: line 908 css - #footer {
    background: url("images/bgr-box-trans.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #E4E2DB;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEECE6;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 960px;
}

Comment: Hello Sir I did it but nothing happened can it be a conflict with other stuff? Thank you very much sir

Comment: Hello Sir, I've now worked it out thank you for being so kind thank you so much :)